# How to Manually Installing and Checking the Version of Libksba8 in a Docker Ubuntu Image

Tags: package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

I pull the UBUNTU docker image, run the downloaded ubuntu image and I run the following command
`dpkg -s libksba8` to check the current version of libksba8 inside the docker ubuntu system.

When I run the above command the output look like this

```
dpkg-query: package 'libksba8' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

So that I download the libksba8 library from the source archive file and I install it manually like this below

- Download file `wget https://www.gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.6.3.tar.bz2`
- Extract the downloaded file `tar xjf libksba-1.6.3.tar.bz2`
- Enter to the extracted folder `cd libksba-1.6.3`
- Configure the package `./configure`
- Build the package `make`
- Install the library `make install`

After the installation I check the libksba8 version again and then I got like this below but what I want to ask about it is I install the version libksba-1.6.3 why the below command showing version 1.6.0-2ubuntu0.2.

```
root@93a9456ee052:/app/libksba-1.6.3# dpkg -s libksba8
Package: libksba8
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 302
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libksba
Version: 1.6.0-2ubuntu0.2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgpg-error0 (>= 1.14)
Description: X.509 and CMS support library
 KSBA (pronounced Kasbah) is a library to make X.509 certificates as
 well as the CMS easily accessible by other applications.  Both
 specifications are building blocks of S/MIME and TLS.
 .
 KSBA provides these subsystems: ASN.1 Parser, BER Decoder, BER
 Encoder, Certificate Handling and CMS Handling.
 .
 This package contains the runtime library files.
Homepage: https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/libksba/
Original-Maintainer: Debian GnuTLS Maintainers <pkg-gnutls-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It's unlikely that ./configure / make / make install created and installed a .deb file, most often that just installs files locally (to /usr/local/lib for example) by default. It looks like you did install the libksba8 package from the Ubuntu repository at some point, and that's what dpkg is seeing.

Comment: @David Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @steeldriver Actually this libksba8 library automatically install when I make ```sudo apt-get update``` but I want to override the version.

Comment: OK well `dpkg -s` is only going to tell you about packages installed via dpkg (or via apt - which uses dpkg under the hood)